# Cannot upload any files in Devdemon Updater

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-updater

When attempting to upload modules to Updater I get this error:

> Server responded with a 404 status

When I click "Show More" it just says **Object not found!** in the detailed view.

I am using FTP upload mode.

This exact same behavior occurs when attempting to backups EE/DB, except it returns the following status line:

> Unexpected server response, probably a PHP error.

When I click "Show More" here, however, it's just the same 404 page as above (Object not found!).

Anyone know how to make this addon work?

**EE version**: 2.7.3 (attempting to get this addon working so I can update to 2.9.0)

**Updater version**: 3.2.17

Comment: Have you tested your configuration? Most likely you have an ajax error, either cross domain or ACT url can't fire. Test your ACT urls first to make sure things are working. If you still have problems contact DevDemon support for this.

Comment: Thanks for this, it turned out to be a problem with the ACT URL: the value held was index.php?ACT=27, I added a forward slash before and it worked. Edit: I don't see how to accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't accept my comment as answer, since I really just asked a question and you figured it out.